# How to convert NetCDF file to Grib2 or Grib files

Tags: netcdf, grib-2

I'm in trouble to read `NetCDF` file data. Basically NetCDF file contains Ocean current data.
How do you convert a NetCDF file to a `Grib2 or Grib file`? I already have procedure to read data from Grib2 file using `OpenGrads version 2.0.`
What I need overall is to generate image for ocean current components available in netCDF and display on map.

Can anyone direct/correct me how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

GRIB is more limited than NetCDF.  You can use a tool like the NetCDF-Java library to read both NetCDF and GRIB1 and GRIB2 files:  https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/thredds/current/netcdf-java/documentation.htm  However, it can write only NetCDF files.

If you use Matlab, the https://github.com/nctoolbox/nctoolbox can read and plot both.

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem when you try to read a netcdf file in grads?

The command in grads to read netcdf file is

```
sdfopen filename.nc
```

Verify the content with

```
q file 1
```

From this point the procesure is pretty much the same of a grib file.

[]

Answer (score 0):

use the command **gdalwarp** which is able also to convert the CRS (Coordinate Reference System)

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of netCDF filename.grb2 filename.nc
```